# Customer getting R6002 runtime error when using our app

Tags: windows, visual-c++, runtime-error

We have an application built with Visual C++ 2005, and one customer has reported that he's getting this runtime error:

> `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library`
>   `Runtime Error!`
>   `Program: [path to our application]`
>   `R6002`
>   `- floating point support not loaded`

According to Microsoft ([on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1x26e0x%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)), the possible reasons for this are:

- the machine does not have an FPU (not in this case: the customer has an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU and I haven't seen a machine without FPU since the 486SX)
- printf or scanf is used with a floating-point format specification but there are no FP variables in the program (our app contains FP variables but I'm pretty sure we never use printf or scanf with FP formats)

  Something to do with FORTRAN (no FORTRAN code in our app)

Also, the error is occurring while they're using our application (specifically, just after they select a file to be processed), not when the application starts up.

I realise this is a long shot, but has anyone seen anything like this anywhere before? Google was pretty unhelpful (there were lots of unsupported claims that it was a symptom of some kind of virus infection but very little apart from that).

Any suggestions gratefully received :-)

Comment: Long shot - running against a different version of the runtime library? Does your file processing step load a separate DLL with a different runtime version?

Comment: We don't explicitly load any other DLLs. Could loading a DLL with a different runtime version trigger the error I mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you linking a static version of the CRT?  If so, you need to have floating point variables in the binary that calls printf().  And these variables have to be really used (i.e not optimized out by the comppiler).

Another possibility is a race between the CRT initialization and the code that uses these FP routines, but that would be hard to produce.

Comment: Yes, we're linking a static version of the CRT. There are definitely FP variables in there, they're really used, and I can't find any instances at all of us using any variant of printf with FP format specs. If there were a race condition involving CRT init, wouldn't that happen when the app was starting, rather than in mid-flow?

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it's likely to be useful to other people, even though it didn't directly solve my problem.

Comment: @Anodyne: what (if anything) did directly solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

R6002 can be caused by printf trying to print a string that contains a percent-sign.
Most likely root cause of such printf failure is a program that manipulates arbitrary files and prints their names.  Amazing to me, there really ARE people who put percent-signs in file names!  (Yes, I realize that is technically legal.)

Comment: That's interesting... presumably it would only happen if you're using unsanitized input as the format string for printf? I've been burned by that one in the past - I've long since learned to do printf("%s", var) rather than printf(var) :-)

Answer (score 0):

printf("%f\n", (float)rand() / RAND_MAX);

I experienced the same runtime error in a program compiled with VS2010 command line cl.
The reported error occurred *without* the (float) cast and disappeared when I added it.